# How can I solve this SQL Python problem fetching it the right way?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

When I create the DataBase CURRENT_users.db:

```
    import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('CURRENT_users.db')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
          id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
          nome TEXT NOT NULL,
          email TEXT NOT NULL,
          created_in DATE NOT NULL,
          password TEXT NOT NULL

)
""")

print("Success! DATABASE created with success!")

conn.close()

import UserLoginUI_Part2_Tes
```

t1

And I insert the DATA:

```
    import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("CURRENT_users.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()


cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO users (id, nome, email, created_in, password)
VALUES (001, "Renatinho", "renato@Outlook.com", 2055-4-21, "passtest");
""")


conn.commit()

print("A new user has been incremented! Now,have fun!!!")

conn.close()

import UserInterface
```

In "UserInterface", I type "Renatinho" (that's my NOME data),it seems like that "IF" doesn't work!!

```
    import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("CURRENT_users.db")

cursor = conn.cursor()

user_INFO = cursor.execute(""" SELECT nome FROM users; """)

user_in_SCRIPT = str(input("Your credentials: USERNAME: \n>>>"))

logged_in = False;

if user_in_SCRIPT == user_INFO:
      print("You are logged in! Enjoy your new account...")
      logged_in = True;

else:
      print("Error: Not a valid user or USERNAME!!")
      conn.close()
```

And it ever shows me the ELSE "command block"..

Please,who can help me?

Thanks for everything...

Comment: You've forgotten a step. You need to use `fetchone()` or `fetchall()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've called SQL SELECT but you need to fetch the data.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT nome FROM users")
user_INFO = cursor.fetchone()
```

This would return a tuple, so to get the string inside, take the zero index:

```
if user_in_SCRIPT == user_INFO[0]:
    print("You are logged in! Enjoy your new account...")
    logged_in = True
```

BTW, you're in Python, not JavaScript. You don't need to end statements with semicolons. :-)